# Get chunks from the bytes of a PNG in C

Tags: arrays, c, image, file, binary

I'm trying to separate the chunks of a png's bytes in C. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics), A png's chunks are structured with 4 bytes depicting the length of the data to come, 4 bytes depicting the type of chunk, data of length previously described, and a 4 byte crc. Im new to C, but Im proficient in Python. So if some of my practices may look a bit weird or overdone, this is because I was trying to make them look like things ive used in python. Please correct me on the proper way to do things if you see these!

So far, I've created a struct with an int member called length, two unsigned char arrays for type and crc, and an unsigned char pointer for data (since the length is determined later). My current method is to increase segment by segment in a forever loop until I reach the end chunk, at which point I would break. When I determine the values of the current chunk, I reallocate space to a temp variable to make space for the new  value.

I didn't know how I would do this since lengths of arrays need to be determined at initialization, and I couldn't find the number of chunks in the bytes since its data is not a known value. So in what one might call I sloppy fashion, I sortof tried to make it work like appending to a list in python, yet I'm not sure how well this would work. I made sure all the compiler errors were fixed, and didn't expect it to work the first time, but I expected it to at least give me *something*. Yet it gave me nothing. And no number of print statements helped me, it never outputted anything. I literally cant figure out whats wrong. Its probably a number of things, but I just cant figure out for the life of me. Here is my code so far:

```
typedef struct Chunk Chunk;
struct Chunk {
    int length;
    unsigned char type[4];
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned char crc[4];
};

Chunk* getChunksFromBytes(unsigned char* bytes)
{
    int next_seg = 8;
    int chunks = 0;
    long int size = 1;

    Chunk new_chunk;
    Chunk* file_chunks = (Chunk*) malloc(sizeof(Chunk));
    Chunk* temp = file_chunks;

    unsigned char end_chunk[4] = {'I', 'E', 'N', 'D'};

    while(1){
        new_chunk.length = bytes[next_seg+1] << 24 |
                           bytes[next_seg+2] << 16 |
                           bytes[next_seg+3] << 8 |
                           bytes[next_seg+4];

        new_chunk.type[0] = bytes[next_seg+5];
        new_chunk.type[1] = bytes[next_seg+6];
        new_chunk.type[2] = bytes[next_seg+7];
        new_chunk.type[3] = bytes[next_seg+8];

        if(new_chunk.type == end_chunk) break;

        unsigned char data[new_chunk.length];
        for(int i = 1; i <= new_chunk.length; i++){
            data[i] = bytes[next_seg+8+i];
        }

        memcpy(new_chunk.data, data, sizeof(data));

        new_chunk.crc[0] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+9];
        new_chunk.crc[1] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+10];
        new_chunk.crc[2] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+11];
        new_chunk.crc[3] = bytes[next_seg+new_chunk.length+12];

        next_seg+=new_chunk.length+12;
        size += sizeof(new_chunk)+1;

        temp = realloc(temp, size);
        temp[chunks] = new_chunk;
        chunks++;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Use `malloc()`, dynamic memory allocation. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm

Comment: @paladin for what part? instead of what? you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: With `malloc()` you can create arrays at runtime. _"I didn't know how I would do this since lengths of arrays need to be determined at initialization..."_. There's are a lot of tutorials out there how to use `malloc()`, I suggest you read one of them.

Comment: BTW If your PNG isn't that big, just copy the entire file into memory and manipulate the entire file, instead of copying little chunks. Do you use Linux as OS? If so, read also about `fmemopen()` and `open_memstream()`.

Comment: No, i meant that the bytes i have read from the file are split into respective chunks, not that I'm loading them in chunks. For example, the chunk `IDAT` contains image information

Comment: Anyway, you should just load all chunks at the same time into an dynamic memory array until you detect chunk IEND. While loading you are able to count the individual chunks. After/While you process this entire chunk array you read your file-header parameters. Read your parameters plain into 'WORDs'/'DWORDs' and apply necessaries byte-shifting after you've read them. Or construct 'WORDs/DWORDs' with ordered bytes as a struct in the first place. This is less prone to errors. PS use an initial buffersize big enough for most cases, so you need only sparingly to increase your buffer.